# Php Mail Queue Exception on Unix - Expert opinion

Tags: php, email, unix, smtp

I am using Mail Queue to send emails in my application (https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue/)

The same code works fine on windows (php version: 5.5.28) and it gives the below mentioned exception on unix (php version 5.6)

`PHP User Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Error in sending mail:  authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: Begin TLS negotiation now)]'`

The mail server credentials are fine. They are same on linux as well as on windows. `Code 220` means `the server  is ready` (via http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-error)

I read somewhere it is due to php5.6 and it will work fine on 5.5 but I don't think so that would be a valid answer/solution to the problem.

Comment: Do you have any firewall running on your Unix server?

Comment: Err, I remember, I had encountered almost similar error while migrating my app on cloud. I am not sure but its probably the PHP version problem. Try turning off openssl extension in php .

Comment: any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Are using SSH or tools like Cpanel / Webmin to manage your server?

Comment: ssh, I have bought a server from amazon, installed php, mysql, deployed all the applications..Working all fine..Now the remaining part is sending emails via CRON..

Comment: Huh, so u r using AWS EC2 as server?

Comment: yes...right..@EntrePrAmar

Comment: I can't see open ssl extension in php.ini

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109269/discussion-between-entrepramar-and-danyal-sandeelo).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because PHP 5.6 does SSL peer verification by default and PHP 5.5 doesn't. I guess if you fix a valid SSL certificate it should work, or disable ssl verify-peer in your code.

Without knowledge of Mail_Queue I don't know how to fix it without any example code.

Comment: any idea how can I do that? I am not explicitly defining it in my code

Answer (score 0):

Sending emails from EC2 instances is limited by Amazon and strictly throttled at network level. This is to prevent spamming and other abuses.

If you have a large amount of emails to send to your customers, the recommended way is to use [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email.html). With Amazon SES, you can send transactional email, marketing messages, or any other type of high-quality content and you only pay for what you use.

[Connecting to the Amazon SES SMTP Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-existing-server.html)

If you really need to send emails from an EC2 instance, you must use an Elastic IP Adress and ask Amazon's support to remove limitations on SMTP traffic from that EIP.

Alternatively I will suggest you can use [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/), they are fast and accurate, provides 12000 emails per month for free as well.

Comment: I can send emails via my frontend..email are sent and it is working all fine..The issue is sending them via mail_queue

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, to be honest I have never used mail_queue. Check if mail_queue trying to connect using port 25. If so try other ports.